# Computing the cohomology groups of the Klein bottle as a $\Delta$-complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, klein-bottle

I am currently working on how to compute the cohomology and ring structure of certain surfaces who are given as $\Delta$-complexes such as the Kein bottle pictured below.

[image]

For this i encountered this particular answer:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/877083/543570

Unfortunately, i do not understand why it holds that

$\operatorname{Im}\delta:C^1 \rightarrow C^2=\langle \mu+\lambda, \mu- \lambda\rangle=\langle2\mu, \mu+\lambda\rangle=\langle\mu +\lambda\rangle$

and

$\ker \delta:C^1 \rightarrow C^2=\langle\beta+\gamma,\alpha +\beta\rangle$

where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are the dual basis elements of $a,b,c$ respectively and $\mu,\lambda$ the dual basis elements for $U,L$ respectively.

Could someone help me understand why $\operatorname{Im}\delta = \langle\mu +\lambda\rangle$ and $\ker \delta = \langle\beta+\gamma,\alpha +\beta\rangle$ ?

Unfortunately i can't provide any own attempts since i got stuck at these two computations and do not know how to continue.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876296/cohomology-ring-of-klein-bottle-over-mathbbz-2/877083#877083) that you link, recall that the dual $\mu\in C^2(K,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ of $U$ is the linear map defined to be $1$ at $U$ and $0$ at $L$ (since $C_2(K,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is spanned by $U$ and $L$). Similarly, $\lambda$ is the dual of $L$, so it is $1$ at $L$ and $0$ at $U$.

**Image**

In the answer, $\delta(\alpha)$, $\delta(\beta)$ and $\delta(\gamma)$ are computed, i.e. the image of the generators of $C^1$ are computed. In particular $\delta(\alpha)(U)=1=\delta(\alpha)(L)$. Since $\delta(\alpha)$ is a linear combination of $\lambda$ and $\mu$, and its values at $U$ and $L$ are both $1$, it follows that $\delta(\alpha)=\mu+\lambda$.

**Kernel**

An element of $C^1$ that belongs to the kernel of $\delta$ is a combination of $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ that is sent to $0$ by $\delta$. Since we have the images $\delta(\alpha)$, $\delta(\beta)$ and $\delta(\gamma)$, and since we are over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ we can simply check which combinations yield $0$. For instance, $\delta(\alpha)(U)=\delta(\beta)(U)$ and $\delta(\alpha)(L)=\delta(\beta)(L)$ (equalities in $\mathbb{Z}_2$), so $\delta(\alpha+\beta)=0$ because $\delta(\alpha+\beta)(V)=0$ for all $V\in C_2$, since $C_2$ is spanned by $U$ and $L$, both on which $\delta(\alpha+\beta)$ vanishes.

Can you follow from here?

Comment: Thank you vm, i think i might understand the image, would you mind elaborating how the kernel is being computed?

Comment: Okay I added an explanation of how to find the kernel.

Comment: Thank you very much Javi, give me a day to carefully go over it, i might return if i have some questions. Thank you so much!

Comment: Take your time!

Comment: Hi Javi, thanks again for the help. Does $\delta(\alpha) = \lambda + \mu$ follow from $$\delta(\alpha)(U) = \lambda(U) + \mu(U)$$ and $$\delta(\alpha)(L) = \lambda(L) + \mu(L)$$ ?

Comment: Yes, indeed. The maps $\delta(\alpha)$ and $\lambda+\mu$ have the same values on base elements so they must be equal.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and patience Javi, both answers helped me a lot. I am really thankful to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

In the linked question, with $\alpha$ dual to $a$, etc., and $\mu, \lambda$ dual to $U, L$, the author says [I've added sequence numbers]

> 1. To compute cohomology we need the homology groups of the chain complex: $0 \rightarrow C^0 \rightarrow C^1\rightarrow C^2 \rightarrow 0\rightarrow ...$, so we compute the coboundary map.

> 2. $\delta(\phi)(a)=\phi(\partial(a))=\phi(v)-\phi(v)=0=\delta(\phi)(b)=\delta(\phi)(c)$, so $\delta:C^0 \rightarrow C^1$ is the zero map.

> 3. $\delta(\alpha)(U)=\alpha(\partial(U))=\alpha(a)+\alpha(b)-\alpha(c)=1+0-0=1$.

> 4. Similarly, $\delta(\beta)(U)=1$ and $\delta(\gamma)(U)=-1$. And $\delta(\alpha)(L)=1$, $\delta(\beta)(L)=-1$, $\delta(\gamma)(L)=1$.

> 5. So $\delta:C^1 \rightarrow C^2$ takes $\alpha \rightarrow \mu +\lambda$, $\beta \rightarrow \mu -\lambda$, and $\gamma \rightarrow -\mu +\lambda$. Thus:

> 6. Im $\delta:C^1 \rightarrow C^2=<\mu+\lambda, \mu- \lambda>=<2\mu, \mu+\lambda>=<\mu +\lambda>$ since we are over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Now let's recall that $a,b,c$ generate $C_1$, and $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ generate $C^1$, etc. Item 4 says that $\delta(\alpha)$ can be determined, as an element of $C^2$, by what it does to generators (i.e.  $U$ and $L$) for $C_2$. From item 3, we have that $\delta(\alpha)(U) = 1$; item 4 says $\delta(\alpha(L)) = 1$. Now the question is "what linear combination of the basis elements $\lambda$ and $\mu$ *also* has these properties, for every element of $C^2$ is a combination of the basis elements. The answer is that $\lambda + \mu$ does. Hence
$$
\delta(\alpha) = \lambda + \mu.
$$
You can use the same process to figure out what delta does to the other two generators for $C^1$. When you're done, you've got three elements of $C^2$ which **span** the image of $\delta$. That's what items 5 says.

Item 6 then computes a reduced form of this span, using the fact that you're working over the integers mod 2 to get rid of some stuff.

So...exactly which of the items in the proof is confusing you?

**Post-comment addition**
$$\newcommand{\two}{{\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z}}
$$

$C^1$ is a 3-dimensional vector space over $\two$, with basis $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$; $C^2$ is a 2-dimensional vectorspace over $\two$, with basis $\mu, \lambda$. The function $\delta$ is a linear transformation from the first to the second, and hence can be represented (in these two bases) by matrix multiplication with a $2 \times 3$ matrix, which is
$$
A = \pmatrix{
1 & 1& -1 \\
1 & -1& 1
}
$$
(where do each column's entries come from? Make sure you know!)
but since we're talking about mod-2 stuff, that might as well be
$$
A = \pmatrix{
1 & 1& 1 \\
1 & 1& 1
}
$$
The kernel of $T(v) = Av$ is the same as that of $T(v) = A'v$, where $A'$ is the row-reduced version of $A$, which is
$$
A' = \pmatrix{
1 & 1& 1 \\
0 & 0& 0
}
$$
which you get by subtracting the first row from the second. The first column (corresponding to $\alpha$) contains a leading "1" for some row, but the others do not; they can therefore be treated as free variables. So looking at $x\alpha + y\beta + z\gamma$, $y$ and $z$ are free variables. By assigning $y = 1, z = 0$, we find $x = 1$, i.e., that $\alpha + \beta$
is one generator for the kernel. By assigning $y = 0, z = 1$, we again find $x = 1$, so that $\alpha + \gamma$ is another generator for the kernel. So the kernel is spanned by these two elements. (Of course, there are many other pairs of elements that span it too).

Comment: Thanks John, i think i might have understood the image, but unfortunately i still have issues understanding the kernel. Would you mind helping out on this, too?

Comment: See post-comment addition.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed addendum, i will carefully go over it and will return if i still have questions. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi John, thanks again for the help. Does $\delta(\alpha) = \lambda + \mu$ follow from $$\delta(\alpha)(U) = \lambda(U) + \mu(U)$$ and $$\delta(\alpha)(L) = \lambda(L) + \mu(L)$$ ?

Comment: Yes,exactly: a co-cycle is determined by its values on a basis, so checking it on $U$ and $L$ is enough. We've shown here that $\delta$ and $\lambda+\mu$ have the same values on both $U$ and $L$, hence MUST be equal.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer and your patience John, both answers helped me tremendously! I appreciate your time and effort so much. I will accept Javi's answer since he has less reputation, i hope that's ok. But i really appreciate your help.

Comment: I will reward your answer with some of my reputation nonetheless! Just need to wait 23h.

Comment: Totally fine. I like Javi's answer too. No need to send me any reputation points, really.